# How to get devices on same network with react native

Tags: react-native

I was using arp to get this info, but now arp is blocked on android 10+, how can i remake this funcionality without arp? I already tried react-native-zeroconf but with no success.

Comment: You can't, because `arp` is the way to do that. And if that is blocked by the operating system ...

Comment: @derpirscher so why there are some apps that have this funcionality working in recent android versions, for example "quem esta no meu wifi"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would like to know this as well, have you solved it? Did you try react-native-find-local-devices ?? (https://github.com/RichardRNStudio/react-native-find-local-devices)